# I am getting the Error org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, spring, wcf

I am trying to call a Rest Service with post method. I am getting a bad request Error as mentioned below.
Rest service is developed in WCF, with only one String as request parameter.

**Error Log**

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: [?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/... (3462 bytes)]
```

**Code**

```java
System.out.println("Hi.................... I am in ###########################");
String testData="hashcode";

String response = restTemplate().postForObject("https://(...)/Rest/Register",testData, String.class, testData);
        
System.out.println("Hi.................... I am in ########################### "+response);
```

*Can you please suggest me what's wrong in my calling ?*

Comment: Can you use postman to access the rest service? I need to determine whether it is a client problem or a Rest service problem.

Comment: I tried from Postman, it's working like below. I have used the URL, with POST method type. I have added the Content-type=application/json in headers. Then I directly passed the String in the request body.  My intention is to make it work with Request Body instead of sending as param.

Comment: Generally, 400 Bad Request in WCF service are caused by wrong request format. You need to know the request format of WCF interface. There are help documents in WCF. You can access the help document to view the correct request format.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use just :

```
String response = restTemplate().postForObject("https://(...)/Rest/Register",testData, String.class)
```

Also if this doesn't work could you post your API also?